# iOS 7 tint colour desaturation notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, tintcolor

Does anyone know if there is a notification I can listen to within a UIViewController to know if the tint colour is being desaturated currently due to an alert or popover being shown?

I know i can subclass the specific view and override the `tintColorDidChange:` method to make my changes, but in my design something like a notification is more desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just subclassed UIWindow and did the following?

```
-(void)tintColorDidChange
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tintColorDidChange" object:self];
}
```

As far as I am aware, there is no system notification for this and the above suggestion would only be suitable if you was listening out for app-wide tint colour changes.

If you wanted to be notified about changes to specific views then you would have to subclass them yourself manually.

Comment: Thanks for clarification regarding the system notification, your suggestion would work, I'd just have to override the `window` method in my AppDelegate to use a custom window with my storyboard.